# ViewModelViewHost, what nested view combinations are known to work in XAMFORMS?

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

Thank you up front...can anyone tell me the current supported combinations of nesting views/viewmodels inside other views/viewmodels using XAMFORMS? If I’m using the correct terminology, basically chap 15 to 18 of Boogaart’s book...yes I was that impressed I bought a hard cover book, probably the first in 15 years, but I digress. I got a ReactiveContentView to nest inside a ReactiveContentPage, but have had trouble with other combinations like viewmodelviewhost or a page in a page? For example a carouselpage inside of another page or view? I could probably use a horizontal scrolling stacklayout, but that seems like more work and feels less cool. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We do not really provide help for broad generic questions. I would suggest that you ask a specific question and provide some sample code to accompany your question. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Regards.

Comment: Hi, I have used various combinations of views nested in pages, all accomplished with a ViewModel first approach using ReactiveUI. I also loaded a CarouselView without bigger problems. If you provide a minimal working example of your code we can help troubleshooting your issues https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.